# How to group and rearrange data that are in "full line" mode SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL Datas stored in "full row" that need to be rearranged

Original Data

```
ID      User    Date            Act1   Act2  Act3  Act4 
1       Aba     2019-04-27      3      1     NULL  2
2       Bob     2019-04-28      1      NULL  2     1
3       Carl    2019-04-28      2      1     1     2
4       Dan     2019-04-29      3      2     1     NULL
5       Aba     2019-04-29      4      7     5     NULL
```

Desired state (Per day and Act)

```
ID      2019-04-27    2019-04-28   2019-04-29
Act1       3          3            7
Act2       1          1            9
Act3      NULL        3            6
Act4       2          3            NULL
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION ALL` with condition aggravated function.

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 'Act1' Id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-27' THEN Act1 END) '2019-04-27',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-28' THEN Act1 END) '2019-04-28',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-29' THEN Act1 END) '2019-04-29'
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Act2' Id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-27' THEN Act2 END) '2019-04-27',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-28' THEN Act2 END) '2019-04-28',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-29' THEN Act2 END) '2019-04-29'
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Act3' Id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-27' THEN Act3 END) '2019-04-27',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-28' THEN Act3 END) '2019-04-28',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-29' THEN Act3 END) '2019-04-29'
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Act4' Id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-27' THEN Act4 END) '2019-04-27',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-28' THEN Act4 END) '2019-04-28',
       SUM(CASE WHEN Date = DATE'2019-04-29' THEN Act4 END) '2019-04-29'
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fc8e5/1/0)**:

```
|   Id | 2019-04-27 | 2019-04-28 | 2019-04-29 |
|------|------------|------------|------------|
| Act1 |          3 |          3 |          7 |
| Act2 |          1 |          1 |          9 |
| Act3 |     (null) |          3 |          6 |
| Act4 |          2 |          3 |     (null) |
```

Comment: I had to adapt it to data, took a little time but that's doing the job thanks a lot!